# How to compare HTML input with mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
$query = "
SELECT N.N_ID
     , P.P_ID
     , P.P_F_NAME
     , P.P_L_NAME
     , P.P_ADDR
     , NP.VISIT_TIME
     , N.N_LN_NAME
     , N.N_SPEC
     , M.M_DESC
     , NM.M_DOSE 
  FROM NURSE N
     , patient P
     , n_visit_p NP
     , MEDIC M
     , n_provide_m NM 
 WHERE N.N_ID  = NP.N_ID 
   AND P.P_ID  = NP.P_ID 
   AND M.M_ID  = NM.M_ID 
   AND NP.N_ID = NM.N_ID 
   AND NP.P_ID = NM.P_ID
     , **N.N_ID='{$_GET["nurse_id"]}'**;
     ");

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

This is a part of my code, where i tried to compare the HTML input through $_GET....
"nurse_id" is the form name in HTML through which i am receiving input..
I even tried it with `$N_ID= $_GET["nurse_id"]"`
but its not working either way... 
the result that i am getting is all nurse details but not the specific selected nurse...

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Just sit back and relax. Someone will be by soon to destroy your server and render your question moot.

Comment: 'moot' - I dislike that word; the North American meaning is almost the antonym of the English meaning :-(

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks, now I'm researching moot's various definitions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to use `AND` instead of the comma.

```
"... AND NP.P_ID=NM.P_ID AND N.N_ID='".$_GET['nurse_id']."';");
```

If the nurse id is an integer, you don't need the single quotes:

```
"... AND NP.P_ID=NM.P_ID AND N.N_ID=".$_GET['nurse_id'].";");
```

I *strongly* recommend that you sanitize `$_GET` values before using them to query the database. Even better, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).